# Timestamp conversion while loading data from Teradata data lake to SSMS database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, teradata, data-conversion

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  created_date
  ,created_date = CASE WHEN c.created_date = '' THEN Null ELSE DATEADD(hour,-6,CAST(REPLACE(replace(c.created_date,'t',' '),'Z','') AS DATETIME)) END    
FROM ACE.stg.Datalake_Case C
WHERE created_date = '2019-12-21T01:12:31.000Z'
```

UNALTERED: `2019-12-21 01:12 AM` in the query 
ALTERED: `2019-12-20 06:12 PM`

Comment: In Teradata, the timestamp is showing in EST. Which I need to convert to CST in SSMS

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The above SQL is for SQL Server plus it seems to adjust from UTC to UTC-6 (which would be CST (or MDT during Daylight Saving). For Teradata you would want to know whether the data is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or just TIMESTAMP data type, and what is the session time zone (HELP SESSION)?

Comment: @Andrew I am trying to get the data from my data lake table (source) to SSMS table (destination). I noticed created_date (source column) has timestamp (it shows like this: 2019-12-21T01:12:31.000Z) this data are in EST time zone. I want to convert it to CST when I am loading this data in my destination.